# Sample size requirements in survey

Tags: statistics, sampling

If am doing some market research and want to answer the question "What percentage of the users of a service, searched for the given service online?". Lets say I go out and get people to take a survey.

How do I calculate the required sample size that would create the correct distribution for a given country or region?

Comment: You might want to ask at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If we define *population* as the group of all users of the service, then you want to estimate the *proportion* of population which searched for the service online. The required sample size can be determined based on

- confidence level
- desired size of confidence interval

The determination of sample size is discussed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination#Estimating_proportions_and_means), a worked out example is [given here](http://stattrek.com/estimation/confidence-interval-proportion.aspx) and probably in every statistics textbook.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you ask over at cross validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/